# вопрос про opcache (php)

Tags: php

здравствуйте, есть ли смысл использовать opcache для php, если при этом в конфиге не указывать полное кэширование php файлов?

просто дело в том что я пробовал использовать кэш полностью, но когда я ввожу изменения в скриптах, и делаю opcache reset, то у людей которые в тот момент заходят на сайт, соединение сбрасывается, и Клауд Флэйр выводит bad connection (как при рестарте апача), а меня это не устраивает